# postgres doesn't connect when I enable huge page

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, huge-pages

If I enable `huge_pages=on` in `postgresql.conf` file,
my postgres-14 not connecting
If i disable postgres it connects

can anyone help me?
My OS is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What error message do you get? Is `shared_memory_type` set to `mmap`? What is your hardware system architecture? **Add answers as update to your question**.

Comment: the error is this:
"could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "192.168.0.111" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5051?".

But it connects with huge_page = off .

There must be something missing from the kernel to define.

shared_memory_type was commented out.
Right now it's like mmap, but it didn't solve the problem.

My architecture is amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `huge_pages = on`, the server won't start unless you define enough hugepages on the operating system. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-HUGE-PAGES):

> `huge_pages (enum)`
>
> Controls whether huge pages are requested for the main shared memory area. Valid values are `try` (the default), `on`, and `off`. With `huge_pages` set to `try`, the server will try to request huge pages, but fall back to the default if that fails. With `on`, failure to request huge pages will prevent the server from starting up. With `off`, huge pages will not be requested.
>
> [...]
>
> For more details about using huge pages on Linux, see [Section 19.4.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-HUGE-PAGES).

Comment: I need to use huge_page=on to gain performance.
Do you know if there are some configuration steps in linux?
Because setting only the postgres.conf file does not work.
I couldn't activate it by reading the documentation. https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages

Comment: Look at the link at the end of my answer. You have to explicitly create hugepages.

Comment: vm.nr_hugepages=99 does not run
But with vm.nr_hugepages=3170 it's ok
thanks

Comment: @rivando Thanks for that tip. I followed directions for installing Mayastor on Microk8s Kubernetes and they suggested setting vm.nr_hugepages=1024. Then my postgresql pods were randomly failing and I thought it had to do with the NFS storage being corrupted. Your comment confirms to me that postgresql has a weird issue of silently crashing if there are huge pages but not enough.

Comment: @JVal90 There is no "silent mystery" about that. If you tell PostgreSQL that it must use huge pages or die, and there are not enough huge pages, it will die and write a clear message to the log.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe To clarify, I never modified any configuration on my PostgreSQL pods. The pods worked before I set vm.nr_hugepages=1024, worked after I set vm.nr_hugepages=0, and didn't work in between with the value set to 1024. That sounds much more like a bug (or the pod's configure step messing with postgresql settings depending on detected OS values - which seems like a terrible idea in this case).